# How do I do a DIFF in PIG

Tags: apache-pig, hadoop2

I have 2 data sets on which I am trying to find the difference. I am aware that there are other ways to do the same. What I am interested in is why this snippet of code is failing.

```
A = LOAD 'raw.people1' using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
B = LOAD 'raw.people2' using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
C = COGROUP A BY (name, place, animal, thing) , B BY (name, place, animal, thing) ;
D = FOREACH C DIFF(A, B);
```

A, B and C work correctly. But D fails with the error:
Failed to parse:   Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'DIFF'

Now this should not be the case. The pig docs (http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/func.html#diff) state the DIFF takes two pags as params and A and B are bags of tuples.
What am I missing here?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `GENERATE` keyword before `DIFF` stmt, that is the reason for this error. Can you change like this?

```
D = FOREACH C GENERATE DIFF(A, B);
```

Comment: Yep, looks like the documentation example is incorrect.

Comment: The documentation does not use generate. You are right. Thanks